# JSlider not drawing on null layout JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jslider, null-layout-manager

I have a JPanel that has a null layout and I'm trying to add a JSlider:

```
        slider = new JSlider();


        slider.setSize(300,30);
        slider.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,30));
        int x = (Constants.getScreenWidth()/2)-(slider.getWidth()/2);
        int y = (Constants.getScreenHeight()/2)-(slider.getHeight()/2);
        y = y - 100;
        slider.setLocation(x,y);
        slider.setBounds(x-(slider.getWidth()/2),y-(slider.getHeight()/2),300,30);


        add(slider);
```

however the slider is not showing up. I've printed the slider and it is:

```
javax.swing.JSlider[,420,320,300x30,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=288,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=300,height=30],isInverted=false,majorTickSpacing=0,minorTickSpacing=0,orientation=HORIZONTAL,paintLabels=false,paintTicks=false,paintTrack=true,snapToTicks=false,snapToValue=true]
```

why can't I see the slider?

Comment: never-ever do manual sizing/locating - that's the job of a layoutManager ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- remove `slider.setLayout(null);` you have set for `setLayout(null);` its parent in this case `JPanel.setLayout(null);`
- disclaimer never use `AbsoluteLayout` for placing `JComponent` to the `Container`

I'm able to display JSlider without code line

```
int x = (Constants.getScreenWidth()/2)-(slider.getWidth()/2);
int y = (Constants.getScreenHeight()/2)-(slider.getHeight()/2);
y = y - 100;
slider.setLocation(x,y);
slider.setBounds(x-(slider.getWidth()/2),y-(slider.getHeight()/2),300,30);
```

- place `JComponent` to the `Container` by using `Insets`

this code showed JSlider on the screen

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class NullLayoutManagerWithJSlider extends JFrame {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public NullLayoutManagerWithJSlider() {
        JSlider slider = new JSlider();
        slider.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 30));        
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(slider);

        Insets mmInsets = frame.getInsets();
        Dimension sizeMmInn = null;
        slider.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 30));
        sizeMmInn = slider.getPreferredSize();
        slider.setBounds(20 + mmInsets.left, 16 + mmInsets.top, sizeMmInn.width, sizeMmInn.height);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                NullLayoutManagerWithJSlider cf = new NullLayoutManagerWithJSlider();
            }
        });
    }
}
```